# UV map, UV editing ,i dont know how to add a material

Tags: materials, uv

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bfmO4JmnSmARE-8rq0V78q_EiWS5gf6H/view?usp=sharing

Around 6:10 he adds a UV map changes its name to sandstone and suddenly the wall has sandstone in it I have been following his tutorial and have done exactly what he is doing I am on 2.91 he is using 2.81.
i don't know how to add the sandstone to my wall.
Any suggestion would be helpful

Here is my file (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hj42yRmDqFW306wksIwvbBJppKzvoaoT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: hello, your link ask for registration, maybe use another one?

Comment: hi i did, the video is from udemy (creating 3d environments in blender) by Rob tuytel

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 3:30 he shows a *UV Map* node but he explains that for the moment the UV map itself doesn't exist (the name appears red), so as soon as it is created (6:10) it will switch from default to this UV map.

Comment: OMG thank you so much you are right i forgot that i had spell it wrong in the node so when i type sandstone nothing happen because the spelling was sanfstone in my node. i was getting so frustrated over this xd thanks again and i have sub you on yt :)

Comment: ah ah ok thanks  ;)